# Retaining Label and Literal controls after post back fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am dealing with a very unusual situation through which made me go through the effort of putting up for some answers.

I am trying to regenerate some controls based on the following document,

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3684/Retaining-State-for-Dynamically-Created-Controls-i

This approach works TextBox controls but does not seem to respond to Label, Literal, UploadFile or other controls that I'm not aware of.

I do understand this not working for UploadFile due to security reasons, but why not for other non TextBox controls?

The above article suggests that if we maintain the ID of a control, we can retain them after post back but in the following implementation I only get the TextBox responding to this solution.  The "Label" and "Literal" controls in this situation are lost after PostBack which is undesirable given that I pretty much follow the recipe line by line.

Can someone please have a look at the following implementation and see where I'm going wrong or if I got the whole concept wrong in a way?

This is a counter to keep track of the number of control sets generated,

```
protected int NumberOfControls
{
    get { return (int)ViewState["NumControls"]; }
    set { ViewState["NumControls"] = value; }
}
```

This is the Page_Load event that fetches the previous slides from the DB on initial page load and regenerates the same page on Postback.  AddSlide is a "Placeholder" control where I post other Controls into.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        this.NumberOfControls = PopulateCarouselSettingFields(AddSlides);

    }
    else
    {
        this.GenerateControls();
    }
}
```

This is the definition for "PopulateCarouselSettingsFields".

```
public static int PopulateCarouselSettingFields(PlaceHolder _AddSlides)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    int counter = 0;

    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["someconn"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        conn.Open();

        SqlCmd.Connection = conn;
        SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlCmd.CommandText = "storedprocedure";

        SqlDataReader dReader;

        dReader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dReader.Read())
        {
            Literal lit1 = new Literal();
            lit1.ID = "Lit1_" + counter;
            lit1.Text = "<div class=\"controls controls-row\"><div class=\"span3\">";
            _AddSlides.Controls.Add(lit1);

            Label CarouselTextLabel = new Label();
            CarouselTextLabel.ID = "CarouselTextLabel" + counter;
            CarouselTextLabel.Text = "Carousel Text";
            CarouselTextLabel.Font.Bold = true;
            CarouselTextLabel.CssClass = "control-label";
            _AddSlides.Controls.Add(CarouselTextLabel);

            TextBox CarouselText = new TextBox();
            CarouselText.ID = "CarouselText" + counter;
            CarouselText.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
            CarouselText.Height = 50;
            CarouselText.Text = dReader["CarouselText"].ToString();
            _AddSlides.Controls.Add(CarouselText);

            Literal Lit2 = new Literal();
            Lit5.ID = "Lit2_" + counter;
            Lit5.Text = "</div></div></div><br />";
            _AddSlides.Controls.Add(Lit2);

            counter++;

            }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

This is supposed to regenerate or re-state all the controls using their IDs upon PostBack called from Page_Load event.

```
protected void GenerateControls()
{
    int count = this.NumberOfControls;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        Literal lit1 = new Literal();
        lit1.ID = "Lit1_" + i.ToString();
        AddSlides.Controls.Add(lit1);

        Label CarouselTextLabel = new Label();
        CarouselTextLabel.ID = "CarouselTextLabel" + i.ToString();
        AddSlides.Controls.Add(CarouselTextLabel);

        TextBox CarouselText = new TextBox();
        CarouselText.ID = "CarouselText" + i.ToString();
        AddSlides.Controls.Add(CarouselText);

        Literal Lit2 = new Literal();
        Lit2.ID = "Lit2_" + i.ToString();
        AddSlides.Controls.Add(Lit2);
    }
}
```

The following piece of code adds new set of controls to the Placeholder "AddSlides" container.

```
protected void AddMoreSlidesToCarousel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Literal lit1 = new Literal();
    lit1.ID = "Lit1_" + NumberOfControls.ToString();
    lit1.Text = "<div class=\"controls controls-row\"><div class=\"span3\">";
    AddSlides.Controls.Add(lit1);

    Label CarouselTextLabel = new Label();
    CarouselTextLabel.ID = "CarouselTextLabel" + NumberOfControls.ToString();
    CarouselTextLabel.Text = "Carousel Text";
    CarouselTextLabel.Font.Bold = true;
    CarouselTextLabel.CssClass = "control-label";
    AddSlides.Controls.Add(CarouselTextLabel);

    TextBox CarouselText = new TextBox();
    CarouselText.ID = "CarouselText" + NumberOfControls.ToString();
    CarouselText.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
    CarouselText.Height = 50;
    AddSlides.Controls.Add(CarouselText);

    Literal Lit2 = new Literal();
    Lit2.ID = "Lit2_" + NumberOfControls.ToString();
    Lit2.Text = "</div></div></div><br />";
    AddSlides.Controls.Add(Lit2);

    this.NumberOfControls++;
}
```

Comment: Could you give us a bit of background on why you are using dynamic controls? Maybe there is a simpler way to achieve what you want without relying on dynamically created controls (repeaters, grids with tweaking visibility based on conditions etc). You can do most things without resorting to dynamic controls, and your life will be easier as a result...

Comment: I basically want to have a series of controls to be reproduced on user request.  In this case I'm dealing with a front page carousel setting where the user is able to configure the "image", "text", "button" and a "link" associated to each slide on the carousel.  The user presses "Add More" and a new series of controls should appear taking user's information for each slide.  This info should be stored into the DB and be retrieved to the same settings page upon initial load.

Comment: Sounds like a job for an `<asp:Repeater ...>` control. Use a `div` (or similar) as the Carousel container, add a repeater in the div and in the codebehind fetch the data from db, bind it to the repeater. Then in the client `js` you can show/hide one slide at a time and have a link to a separate page where the user can add a new slide. After adding the new slide, it will be stored in db and when going back to the front page, the repeater will be bound again and the new slide will be in the carousel.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to put it like this, but the article you are relying on is doing it wrong.

Dynamically created controls MUST be created in Page_Init, so that they exist before any ViewState stuff. Also, dynamically controls must be recreated each and every time the Page is initialized, PostBack or not.

ViewState/PostBack do not "retain" controls, only the state of such controls.

Please read this article: [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the useful link.  Then how come the TextBox control works just fine reinstating its values but not the Label and Literal controls?

Comment: Does it really? You're filling the TextBox.Text with a value from the database. Does it reinstate a value you're typing into it?

Comment: Interestingly Yes.  That's why I'm enormously confused and can't find a reason why there is such behavior.